# different between p4 sync ...#123456 and p4 sync ... #123456

Tags: perforce

Dear,

I found I made a mistake recently by using p4 sync command, where I put extra space between "..." and @123456.

It supposed to be **`"p4 sync ...@123456", but I used "p4 sync ... @123456"`**

Could anyone help explain what it can happen with this wrong command ? I didn't feel diffference, but someone told me it is wrong, I would like to understand and figure out more here.

Thanks.

Wangyang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces separate arguments (in any CLI app, including `p4`).

Perforce lets you combine a file specification and a revision specification into a single argument.  When they're combined, you get their intersection.

Most p4 commands that operate on files accept multiple arguments, and when multiple arguments are specified, it's equivalent to invoking the command on each arg individually, so the net effect is usually a union (although not all commands are idempotent or combinable, so interactions that make it not exactly a union operation are possible).

Hence:

```
p4 sync ...@123456
```

means "sync everything under the current directory `...` to the revision `@123456`".

```
p4 sync ... @123456
```

means the same as:

```
p4 sync ...
p4 sync @123456
```

that is, "sync everything under the current directory `...` to the head revision, and then sync everything in the workspace to the revision `@123456`."

If the current directory is the workspace root, then the net effect of these operations will be the same (although the command might do some extra work in syncing everything to `#head` before it syncs it back to `@123456`).  If the current directory is a subfolder in the workspace, the effect will be very different since you'll sync a bunch of other stuff in your workspace to `@123456` that the first version of the command wouldn't.

Comment: Another way to look at it is "space means OR, no space means AND."

Comment: Yes, except multiple args aren't generally combined in any particularly logical way, just applied sequentially.  In the example of syncing the same file path in different ways, conceptualizing it as an `OR` might lead you to think that it'll combine them and take the max (which is how revision ranges and wildcard operations normally work), but that's not actually what happens.  Most of the time you just don't want to pass multiple arguments in the first place.

Comment: thank you very much, guys, it is very clear to me now